# Ho do I calculate the sum of each labels which are represented in numbers in pandas?

Tags: python

I have a data,

```
   pd= Index   Col1
        A       10
        B       10  
        C       9
        D       9
        E       8
```

I can get the frequency of each values in Col1 using valuecount() but how do I get the sum along with it.
I want the output to be like,

```
   output = Index  Freq  Sum
              10     2    20
              9      2    18
              8      1    8
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
df['tmp'] = df['Col1']
df.groupby("Col1")['tmp'].agg(Freq='size', Sum='sum').reset_index().rename({'Col1': 'Index'}, axis='columns')

   Index  Freq  Sum
0      8     1    8
1      9     2   18
2     10     2   20
```

Answer (score 1):

How about just calculating `Freq * Index`?

Comment: Yeah I though about it too

Comment: So what's the problem?